# How do Capture mac address with Delphi xe6

Tags: delphi, mac-address, delphi-xe6

How get mac address all of adapter with delphi xe6?
i get ip adreess

```
function MyFunction():String;
var
  registro  : TWSAData;
begin
  try
    WSAStartup(257, registro);
    Result := String(Trim(String(inet_ntoa(PInAddr(GetHostByName(nil)^.h_addr_list^ )^ ))));
    WSACleanup;
  except
    on Exp:Exception do
    begin
      Result := 'ERRO_IPCOMPUTADOR';
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: And it seems like there are more help in this question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325872/detect-an-internet-connection-activation-with-delphi/331421#331421

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550672/delphi-get-mac-of-router

Comment: I will see and try it, thanks...

Comment: Since Windows XP, the preferred way to obtain adapters information is the [GetAdaptersAddresses function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915(v=vs.85).aspx). I've provided an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577071/how-do-i-get-the-mac-address-of-a-network-card-using-delphi/33753784#33753784) showing its usage